# PHP - Como adicionar conteúdo ao log?

Tags: php

O log aponta erro de variáveis e funções indefinidas. Mas não é constante (erro/s).

Essas variáveis são definidas por meio de POST, então caso seja feito um GET o erro é gerado.

Analisando o arquivo individualmente ele não contem erros de sintaxe e nem de lógica, porém diariamente o erro se repete.

**Eu gostaria de saber o caminho que o usuário faz para gerar o erro.**

**Existe uma maneira de adicionar ao final de todo registro de log a ultima página acessada pelo usuário ?** Procurando achei `error_prepend_string` e `error_handler`

O resultado que quero obter é algo parecido com :

```
Call to undefined function have_posts() in D:\home\site\index.php on line 22 - **ultima pagina visitada .com.br**
```

O que devo fazer para obter este resultado ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) para gerar mensagens de erro customizadas para todos os níveis ou apenas os que te interessarem. Essa função é chamada antes do tratamento de erro padrão do PHP.

Exemplo do manual (reduzido):

```
// error handler function
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting, so let it fall
        // through to the standard PHP error handler
        return false;
    }

    switch ($errno) {
    case E_USER_ERROR:
        echo "<b>My ERROR</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        echo "  Fatal error on line $errline in file $errfile";
        echo ", PHP " . PHP_VERSION . " (" . PHP_OS . ")<br />\n";
        echo "Aborting...<br />\n";
        exit(1);
        break;

    case E_USER_WARNING:
        echo "<b>My WARNING</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    case E_USER_NOTICE:
        echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;

    default:
        echo "Unknown error type: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
        break;
    }

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}

// set to the user defined error handler
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu usaria o try/catch junto com o file_put_contents para gravar os dados. Por exemplo:

```
try {
    function_que_pode_dar_erro();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    file_put_contents('logfile.log', 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL . print_r($_POST, true).PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
    exit; // pode dar exit para não continuar a execução ou fazer outra coisa
}
```

Comment: Eu vou aplicar isso mas gostaria de fazer para qualquer erro, estou tendo problemas para localizar o local onde certos erros estão sendo gerados.